# WPF Window minimize / maximize behavior not consistent

Tags: c#, wpf

I am dabbling in WPF for the first time and decided I wanted to create a basic application to run in the system tray. I added a winforms NotifyIcon and am able to minimize to the tray and hide the window, so that all is working fine.

Here is where things get weird.

I decided to hide the application from the task bar at all times and to show the `notifyicon` in the system tray at all times. I added click event handlers so that clicking the notifyicon when the window was up would cause it to hide, and then clicking when it was down would cause it to display, pretty standard stuff.

Lastly, the window starts off minimized to the tray.

So, I start my application and all i have is a system tray icon. I click it, and the window displays as you'd expect. I click the notifyicon again and the window disappears, again just as you'd suspect. I click it a third time and instead of my window popping up, I get just the title bar (icon in the upper left, minimize / close buttons etc in the upper right) in the lower left corner. I believe this is the "collapsed" behavior. The last thing that makes this weird is that I am using `WindowLayout = none` so my window doesnt even have a title bar.. and yet one shows up in the lower left corner.

If I click a 4th time, the bar disappears. And so on.

So the hiding / displaying is working the first time and after that it goes weird.

Really scratching my head on this one. Anybody seen anything like this or have any suggestions?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088892/impossible-to-restore-application-hidden-programmatically
This dude explains almost exactly the behavior I am seeing but unfortunately he didnt have his question answered.

Here is the **XAML**:

```
    <Window x:Class="Tagalong.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Tagalong Beta .1" Height="350" Width="500" Icon="content/tagalong_icon.ico"     
    ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Topmost="True"
    WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True" ShowInTaskbar="false" >
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"  />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Name="LeftPane" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black"
    BorderThickness="1.5" Height="350" Width="250" CornerRadius="10"  Background="Blue" >
        <Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Border Name="RightPane" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  
    BorderThickness="1.5" Height="350" Width="250" CornerRadius="10" Background="Green">
        <Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Here is the **Code**:

```
    void InitializeSystemTrayOptions()
    {
        notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"C:\dev\desktop\Tagalong\Tagalong\tagalong_icon.ico");
        notifyIcon.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(notifyIcon_MouseClick);            
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }

    void notifyIcon_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
            {
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }

    private NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
```

Comment: Testing farther... if I set the ShowInTaskBar property in the Window XAML to True... after I click the notifyicon to show the window, then again to minimize it, and click it a 3rd time, it shows on the task bar instead of showing the collapsed title bar in the lower left corner. However this is still not the advertised behavior because its just showing me a taskbar icon. I can click the taskbar icon and THEN it will show the window but it should just be showing when i click the notifyicon.

Comment: Lastly... if I remove the minimize portion and just change visibility, this works as expected. Thats my workaround for now, but I still dont know why minimizing is causing the reported behavior.

Comment: WPF is very different from Winforms in almost every aspect. As such, it has not only different ways to do things but also a different mindset is required. I suggest that if you come from a winforms background, forget everything you've learned and start all over in WPF. otherwise you are going to hit your head against a wall all the time by trying to do things in WPF the winforms way. Another suggestion: Do not reference System.Windows.Forms in a WPF application, otherwise you will never really learn WPF